# How should I use 'please' in a complete sentence?

Tags: subjunctives

> Please?
>
> Please do this.
>
> If it please (you)
>
> May it please you to

This first seems an interrogative phrase, so I guess not a complete sentence. That second may seem an imperative, and or, interrogative, it doesn't seem to contain a subject. This third seems a phrase, closer to a complete sentence maybe. It seems a phrase, maybe a subjunctive phrase? I may not get subjunctives. I may think it like, *If it **pleases** you*. That last seems closest to what I may get to utilize. It seems a dependent clause, I may not get which.

May you write something like this?

> I may like to speak to you, may it please you to.

or,

> May it please you to, I may like to speak to you.

Answer (score 3):

The plain *Please?* would be something uttered after an imperative or statement suggesting a request.  It makes the request sound more polite.  E.g., *Can you bring more eggs?  Please?*

*Please do this* is imperative.  It would follow a statement expressing a need or suggesting a request, e.g. *I need the water refilled.  Please do this.*  (The interrogative of *please do this* would be *Are you doing this?*.)

*If it pleases you* would be something uttered before an imperative or statement suggesting a request.  It makes the request seem optional or extremely polite.  E.g., *If it pleases you, bring your wife to the meeting, we'd love to meet her.*  Avoid using outside of formal business or dinner-party type situations.

*May it please you to* is "*if it pleases you*" multiplied by a factor of 20 or so.  A verb must follow *to*, e.g. *May it please you to know that Charles' wife will not be joining us.*  I as an AmE native don't hear this at all outside possibly movies or TV shows portraying something like a servant confiding important information to his boss (first thing that comes to mind), or someone framing something in an excessively polite manner to be ironic or sarcastic.  Other regions may vary.

Comment: *May it please you* in British English would sound both very high register and possibly archaic, certainly not something a normal English speaker would say I think. Books on mooting for law students suggest opening with "May it please the court, I appear for..." but even in the Senior Courts in England I haven't heard anyone actually say that and I doubt I would. So in the UK a very marked expression too.

Answer (score 3):

"Please do this" is imperative, but the imperative verb is "do," and "please" is just a particle which turns the direct command "do this" into a polite request. It's definitely a sentence, because "do" is a finite verb. This is the most common usage of "please" in English.

"Please?" is a fragment with the same meaning as the above: a request particle.

The latter two examples aren't common modern English. For your two sentences, the idiom would be:

> Please may I speak to you?

or

> May I please speak to you?

or

> May I speak to you, please?

There is another sense in which "please" is used as a verb, but it's far less common; adjectives ("pleasant" for the pleasing thing or "happy" for the pleased person) are more often used for that meaning.

Comment: You weren't particularly direct as to the fact that "if/may it please you"  are _archaic_ (at least, in spoken AmE they are.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @BrianHitchcock. I agree with you, but my aim was to produce an answer suitable for English Language Learners, where brevity is valued, and the way English is used now is more important than the language's history. The questioner's goal seems to be learning to use the word in a sentence in present-day context. That's why I've put all the verb uses of "please" together in that "not common enough to worry about" bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries variously define *please* as an adverb or an interjection. There is also a verb form *to please*.

You are asking about the following four sentences:

> 1. Please?
> 2. Please do this.
> 3. If it please (you)
> 4. May it please you to

1. Interjection: *Please?* is a complete sentence that only makes sense in context.

It softens the previous sentence which would normally be understood to be a command by making it sound more like a request. It could also be pleading, as a child to their parent. *Can I have my friend over? Please? Pleeease?* A child, or someone who wants to be light-hearted might say *Please? Pretty please? Pretty please with a cherry on top?* The cherry on top is a form of bribery, meaning something similar to *I'll really like you if you do this!*

2. Adverb: You may use "please" before or after any command or request in English.

> **Please** get me a glass of water.
>
> Get me a glass of water **please**.

The subject, *you*, is implied because the sentence is using the imperative mode. Here *please* is considered an adverb because it can be replaced by an adverb: *Quickly, get me a glass of water!* or *Get me a glass of water, quickly!*

The sentence may be further softened by the use of *would/will/could/can you*:

> **Please**, *would you* get me a glass of water?
>
> *Would you* **please** get me a glass of water?
>
> *Would you* get me a glass of water **please**?

Using *would/will* makes it a request or a favour, while *could/can* is a polite command. Note: in the past *Can you.../Can I...* meant *Are you able to.../Am I able to...* as in *Can you jump higher than a meter?* Nowadays, the meaning for most people has changed to *Would you.../May I...* with *Can you...* replacing *Would you...* and *Can I...* replacing *May I...*. You may use *please* before or after any of these.

> **Please** *can we* have pizza for dinner?
>
> *Can you* **please** shut the door?
>
> *May I* go out tonight **please**?

3. Verb: Many languages use a phrase where we just say "please" in English:

> English - please
>
> French - s'il vous plaît / s'il te plaît
>
> Dutch - alstublieft / alsjeblieft

The equivalent phrases do exist in English but are not used nearly as much:

```
French  - (si) il vous/te  plaît
                         \/
                         /\
English -  if  it pleases  you
```

and:

```
Dutch   - als tu/je blieft

English -  if  you  please
```

Here *please* is a verb and it conjugates against *it* in the first example and *you* in the second: *it pleases* and *you please*. It is incorrect to say *If it please you* in most varieties of Modern English because *please* is not the right conjugation for *he/she/it*. You have to say *If it please**s** you* instead.

They both sound excessively formal or archaic. If this is the form "please" takes in your first language it might feel more natural to you in English but sounds slightly strange to native English speakers, simply because it is very rarely used. A plain *please* is appropriate for both formal and familiar situations, i.e. you would say it to your boss, the leader of your country, your best friend or to your child.

4. Verb, excessively formal: *May it please you to* is extremely ingratiating or fawning.

It is overly respectful. Since most English speaking countries have lost the class system (where people were ranked into class levels and those in lowers levels were considered inferior to those in higher levels, in comparison to today where there are often laws that specifically state that people are to be treated equally) this form of *please* sounds far too formal. It would be used by an inferior to their superior but nowadays we wouldn't use it except perhaps in surviving ceremonial language (maybe used in courts of law or houses of parliament at certain times). You would only use it in the previously mentioned ceremonies or in jest if you think the other person is behaving in a superior manner. Using this phrase, because it is so uncommon, is supposed to remind the other person that they are acting in an antiquated manner.

Your last two sentences would most commonly be expressed as:

> I would like to speak to you please.
>
> Please may I speak to/with you.

Answer (score 1):

The transitive verb "to please" has a simple literal meaning.   It means something like "to cause pleasure" or "to bring happiness".   The sentences "That pleases me" and "That makes me happy" are generally interchangeable.

English grammar does not distinguish between requests and commands.   We use the imperative mode for both.

There is a real difference between requests and demands, so there has to be a way to indicate that difference.   There are, in fact, a number of ways to represent a request.   "Do this for me" is a command.   "Would you do this for me?" is a question that implies a request.   "I'd like you to do this for me." is a statement that implies a request.

Another way to imply a request is as a conditional command:   "Do this for me if it makes you happy."   "Do this for me if it pleases you."

There are shorter versions of the clause "if it pleases you".   Both "if you please" and simply "please" fulfill the same function.

The interjection "please" is used so commonly for requests that it has come to mean little more than "this is a request".   "Please do this" is a grammatically imperative sentence that semantically expresses a request.   "Would you please do this?" is a grammatically interrogative sentence that semantically expresses a request.

The interjection can stand on its own, as interjections often can.   The grammar (or lack of grammar) of "Please?" resembles that of "Hello." or "Ouch."

> May it please you to, I may like to speak to you.

That sentence does not sound like fluent modern English.   It exhibits a strange or old-fashioned use of the word "may".   It uses a full clause where the one word "please" would suffice.   I must recommend that you avoid this kind flowery language in ordinary discourse.   If nothing else, it's simply gone out of fashion.

Instead, I recommend these:

> I would like to speak to you, please. 
>   I would like to speak to you, if you don't mind.

For the request itself, "would" makes more sense than "may".   The "may" suggests doubt, as if you don't know whether you want to speak.   For the conditional clause, a simple "please" is enough.   If you don't want to use a simple "please", it makes sense to use an entirely different conditional clause.